# PHP Notice - Post Type (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a function to filter products to the end if they are out of stock:

```
add_filter('posts_clauses', 'order_by_stock_status', 60);
function order_by_stock_status($posts_clauses) {
    global $wpdb;
    // only change query on WooCommerce loops
    if (is_woocommerce() && (is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() || is_product_taxonomy())  ) {
        $posts_clauses['join'] .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta istockstatus ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = istockstatus.post_id) ";
        $posts_clauses['orderby'] = " istockstatus.meta_value ASC, " . $posts_clauses['orderby'];
        $posts_clauses['where'] = " AND istockstatus.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND istockstatus.meta_value <> '' " . $posts_clauses['where'];
    }
    return $posts_clauses;
}
```

This causes php warnings:

```
message: "Trying to get property 'post_type' of non-object", file: "wp-includes/class-wp-query.php", line: 4196, …}
```

What can I add to the if statement to stop these warnings?
This fires on my checkout page for some reason.

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like the query modification is _applied_ on the checkout page as well, which probably means the conditions you are checking there are not exhaustive enough to exclude that …?

Comment: Yes I know but I don't know how.

Comment: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-9